# How to init a view controller with custom parameters using factory design pattern

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, init

I am trying to init a view controller with params using my `ViewControllerFactory`. The problem is that I don't know how many parameters will be pass and which type are they.

```
    func createViewController<VC: UIViewController>(storyboardId: String?,
                                                    vcType: UIViewController.Type,
                                                    vcID: String) -> VC? {

        if let storyboardId = storyboardId {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardId, bundle: .main)
            return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcID) as? VC
        } else {
            return vcType.init() as? VC
        }
    }
```

Some view controllers should be instantiated using parameters.  How can I implement it using my factory?
thanks

Comment: I suggest to use the Generic class type parameters. While receiving use a variable like <U> of any class type which is expected to particular vc.

Answer (score 1):

Extract argument passing to the outside of the function with a closure:

```
func createViewController<VC: UIViewController>(storyboardId: String?,
                                                vcType: UIViewController.Type,
                                                vcID: String,
                                                setup: ((VC?)->())? = nil) -> VC? {

    let vc: VC?

    if let storyboardId = storyboardId {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardId, bundle: .main)
        vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcID) as? VC
        setup?(vc)
    } else {
        vc = vcType.init() as? VC
    }

    return vc
}
```

now the one how nows whats to expect from the factory is responsible for passing arguments.

Comment: That's not what I asked,
I want to perform init and not call the function after the init